# Structuring href attribute correctly in sub folder on domain

Tags: html

I have the following website

http://www.bestcastleintown.co.uk/

I have linked several CSS and JS files using HTML such as

```
<link href="../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

However I am now developing a website on a sub directory:

http://www.bestclownintown.co.uk/dev

My CSS and JS links are working on the home page but not on other pages such as about and faq. I have given them the following structure:

```
<link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

What do I need to prefix the value of the `href` attribute with in order for them to be locatable on the sub directory? Should it be `../` ?

Comment: Sticking `/dev` on the end of a URL doesn't make it a subdomain.  Subdomains exist in the host part of the URL. `www` is a subdomain in your example.

Comment: Don't do development in a subdirectory on your live site. Build yourself a proper development server.

Comment: If `../` didn't work, then try `../../`